# Does documentation for file Microsoft.CSharp.targets with default C# targets exist?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

When I create C# project in Visual Studio 2010, file `Microsoft.CSharp.targets` is included.

Is any documentation available for it?
Which targets in it, which properties are used?

It is especially useful when editing build script manually without VS.

The file with targets could be investigated manually (what I do from time to time).
But in such case it is not clear what is a matter of changes, what is by specification and what is no.

Everytime I need something about `Microsoft.CSharp.targets` I found it in different places.
I have not found "one place" with all described.

Does complete reference available?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No specific documentation I know of, it is an implementation detail for C# projects.  You can find plenty of documentation about MSBuild in the MSDN library, the Microsoft.CSharp.targets file just contains targets that are specific to building a C# project.

The most important targets it implements are Build, Clean and Rebuild.  They directly correspond to the commands you find in the VS build menu.  The .csproj file merely sets properties that affect the outcome of the general targets.  All of this is readily available on your machine, you can look at .targets files with an editor.  There's just a whole lot of it and it is isn't exactly that easy to read, the concept of XML as a programming language is a bit, well, flawed.  No debugger either.

Comment: Debugger is already available for MSBuild and works. Not perfect, but sometimes very helpful http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/07/06/debugging-msbuild-script-with-visual-studio.aspx And thanks a lot for detailed explanation, I guessed that I missed something while googling documentation.